# Setting properties to an object in coffee script

Tags: syntax, coffeescript

Say I have an object `alphabets` and I want to set a couple of properties from another object  like-

```
alphabets.a = data.a
alphabets.b = data.b
alphabets.c = data.c
```

Is there a way to remove the redundant usage of the variable `alphabets` and `data`?

**UPDATE:**
Assume that the properties have the same name. Now to remove the over use of property the variable reference `data` I can do the following

```
alphabets = (-> {aa, bb,cc}).call data
```

But the problem is that this will create a new object `alphabets` and what I want is that it should just add the properties to an already available object.

Comment: yes, if there is some relationship between `a` and `aa` in terms of naming... is there?

Comment: lets say there is, then?

Comment: Do you have a real example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @muistooshort I am trying to cherry pick properties from one object and add it to another.

Comment: Where are these properties stored? In your head? In an array? Do they vary at run time? You know, a couple of simple input/output examples would probably clear things up.

Comment: @muistooshort the properties are stored in an object.

Comment: re: update: Law of Demeter comes into play here; I think if you're making a new object to pass into a function, you should just pass the values instead.

Comment: @jcollum Wow! That's a very different approach to solve the problem. I like it!

Comment: Thanks Tushar. That bracket notation comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) of javascript, coupled with coffescript's for/of comprehension:

```
coffee> alphabets
{ a: '1', b: '2', c: '3' }
coffee> data = {}
{}
------> for k,v of alphabets  # use Ctrl-V to get the multiline prompt
.......   data["#{k}#{k}"] = v
[ '1', '2', '3' ]
coffee> data
{ aa: '1', bb: '2', cc: '3' }
coffee>
```